# What is the default nltk part of speech tagset?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

While experimenting with NLTK part of speech tagging, I noticed a lot of `VBP` tags in the output of my calls to `nltk.pos_tag`.  I noticed this tag is not in the Brown Corpus part of speech tagset.  It is however a part of the UPenn tagset.

What tagset does nltk use by default?  I can't find this in the official documentation or the apidocs.

Comment: Looks like it's trained on the Penn Treebank. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L80

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ntlk uses PennTreebank tagset . Have a look at this link http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html

Comment: Provided link is broken. [Apparently different tag-sets](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) are available in NLTK.

Answer (score 5):

It use POS tags used in the Penn Treebank Project. You can see the list of tags with there meaning on 
"http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html"

Answer (score 0):

NLTK uses the [Penn Treebank tagset](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html) as default. Others are available. [Here a list](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html) of other taggers (with other tagsets) available as part of the NLTK library.